# Getting updated state for save in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm quite new to react native and i didn't found any solution to my problem yet so I'm asking here now. I'm trying to update the state of a value on an `onPress` event of a radio button and save it afterwards. The problem is that the save is getting the non updated value. I know `setState` is an async call and a `forceUpdate` is not a recommended solution

I conlsole.log the `handleOnPress` the values are correct

```
import RadioForm, { 
  RadioButton, 
  RadioButtonInput, 
  RadioButtonLabel
} from 'react-native-simple-radio-button'

class SomeClass extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      buttonValues: [{label: "someValue1", value: 0}, 
                     {label:"someValue2", value: 1}],
      someString: "someStringValue_false"
    }

    this.handleOnPress = this.handleOnPress.bind(this),
    this.saveValue = this.saveValue.bind(this)
  }

  handleOnPress(value) {
    if( value === 1 ){
      this.setState({
        someString: "someStringValue_true"
      })
     } else {
      this.setState({
      someString: "someStringValue_false"
     })
    }
   }

   saveValue() {
    //no problem in this function tested already in other cases
   }

  render() {
    return( 
      <View>
        <RadioForm
         radio_props={this.state.buttonValues}
         initial={0}
         formHorizontal={true}
         labelHorizontal={true}
         radioStyle={{paddingRight: 20}}
         buttonColor={"red"}
         selectedButtonColor = {"green"}
         animation={true}
         onPress={(value) => this.handleOnPress(value)}
        />
       <Button
        title={"save"}
        onPress={()=> this.saveValue()}
       />
     </View> 
    )
  }
}
```

I expected that the state will be already set but it keeps the previous state. It's correct if i click twice on the button so the component gets rerendered and the state mutated. As far as I understand it's caused by the async call of `setState`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Don't post duplicate questions.